# QGIS DXF export problem

Tags: qgis, scale

[image]I have a problem exporting a layer into DXF format where when the DXF is opened in QCAD the scale is about 1:100,000,000 and when I scale it to correct size, the x and y scales are not the same. For example a vertical line at 100m long in QGIS turns intoaround  91m on QCAD and a horizontal line 100m long in QGIS turns into around 110m long in QCAD.

The export settings include: the GCS is GDA94 which is correct for my region and the scale is set at 1.
[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you export? - there are a few different ways to export to DXF in QGIS. A screenshot might help with this question.

Comment: Project: Import/Export: Export Project to DXF

Comment: Where can I upload a PNG file to link?

Comment: And right click on layer: Export: Save feature as. This has the same outcome

Comment: Even tried Exporting to PDF and it seems to be saving the same scale inconsistency

Comment: Edit your question there is a bar at the top with the add image option.

Comment: I just edited the post to add two photos. Not sure why three photos were added as I only dragged and dropped 2.

Comment: I just played with scaling on QCAD. To get the dimensions on the DXF file the same as the actual spatial dimensions, I had to scale the DXF elements as follows: first scale x and y by 100,000,000 then scale x = 0.8994, y = 1.0963. As far as I can tell this is a lot different to the difference between projections.